# how to segregate nodes in ANSYS?

Tags: ansys

I have some selected nodes in model, kind of two patches separated at some distance. How to separate these two patches using ANSYS APDL code?
[The image shows selected nodes and local coordinate system created at location, lets say i want to keep only nodes which are near to local coordinate system and the also the nodal distance varies each and every time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHHKd.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for **reselection frum current set**.
Assuming your set is selected and the patch sizes in X-direction is **xwidth**.

You get the nearest set with:

```
nsel,r,loc,X,-xwidth,xwidth
cm,set1,NODE
```

Then Reselect all and unselect first set:

```
alls
cmsel,u,set
cm,set2,NODE
```